# Sharing on Twitter does not show thumbnail of the image

Tags: twitter

I want the users to share a page of my website on Twitter. I've a button as follow:-

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={{title}}&url=http://{{request.get_host}}/ad/{{slug}},{{id}}" target="_blank"></a>
```

My meta tags are as follow:-

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{description}}" />
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://{{request.get_host}}{{images.0}}" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://{{request.get_host}}/ad/{{slug}},{{id}}"/>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="{{request.get_host}}"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="{{title}}" />
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="{{description}}" />
```

[This](https://twitter.com/prafulbagai/status/801785504198819840) is what I get after I click the share link. 
My expected(ideal) result should be like [this](https://twitter.com/prafulbagai/status/801784890538606592). What am I missing?

[This](http://goontrade.com/ad/selling-panda,1/) is the page that I want to share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked your page in the [Twitter Cards Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) and it indicates that the `twitter:description` field is missing. From what you've posted, it is there, but you've added additional content to it (`property="og:description" itemprop="description"`) which means the Cards crawler is unable to parse it correctly. On top of that, I just checked your site, and the value of `twitter:description` is actually blank, so this will not work. I guess `content="{{description}}"` is returning a null value, so you should look into that as well.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the help. Well, I checked into it and the description field was actually empty. Is there a way that I can by-pass this or is it mandatory to provide the description field?

Comment: That's a mandatory field, as you will see in the [Cards documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/cards). You'll need to have your page have a `{{description}}` value that can be passed into the Twitter tag or the validator will not pass the card.

Comment: Here's another helpful SE question about this: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77527/twitter-card-summary-large-image-not-displaying-image/#answer-130911 Apparently sometimes just running your url through their card validator is enough to refresh their image/thumbnail cache for your site. In my case, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I should have provided full url including https:

```
https://dadashkarimi.github.io/images/kernel-379x201.png
```

This is in addition to providing small thumbnail, and adding meta data in my Hugo website.

```
 <meta name="twitter:image" content="{{.Site.Params.websiteURL}}/{{.Params.thumbnail}}">
```